# How to select a value from the dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select the a value from the dropdown list from the site http://www.snapdeal.com/product/samsung-galaxy-grand-duos-i9082/638689?HID=productGrid_mobiles_1

Code used :

```
var obj = document.getElementById('attribute-select-0'); 
    obj.options[1].selected = true;
```

If you manually select the from the dropdown you will see that the href and other attributes of the below div changes as you change the dropdown value

```
console.log(document.getElementById('BuyButton-1').href);
```

**ISSUE** Yhe issue I am facing is that am selecting the dropdown value using the code that i have mentioned above but still am not getting the change expected value in the console.log(document.getElementById('BuyButton-1').href);

**EDIT** Have also tried :

```
obj.selectedIndex = 'White';
```

But same result.

Dont know where am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#attribute-select-0").val("White");
```

Or with plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("attribute-select-0").value="White";
```

Comment: its also causing the same issue as mentioned in the question

Comment: A quick look at fiddler says some ajax calls happening, though can't nail down to the exact script that does the magic. But wondering what the need is, to do this exercise on the snapdeal page!

Comment: Basically I want to click the Buy now button and add the product to cart. But the 'Buy Now' button works only if you select the product color.